# Using an specific format string for numbers

Tags: vb.net

I have some numbers in this format that I would like to change

```
121.23
12312
1.123
1234.5
```

how can I force them to use a format of 12.123 so it has a dot always after the second number.

Comment: so `1.123` should be changed to `11.23`? basic string operations: strip out any existing `.`, split the new string into two parts (first two chars + everything else), then re-join those two parts into a new string with a `.` between.

Comment: If you're trying to "reformat" 1234.5 to 12.345, then that's really not changing the formatting - that's changing the value of the number. Please could you give more details about the context?

Comment: that is correct, everything 11.23 or 12.123 etc.. is this something that can be done only with vb.net format string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a string format operation.  You need to multiply or divide the number by 10 until it's less than 100 or greater than or equal to 10.  Eg:

```
Function Transform(ByVal toTransform As Decimal) As Decimal
    Transform = toTransform

    If (Transform >= 100) Then
        Do While Transform >= 100
            Transform /= 10
        Loop
    ElseIf (Transform < 10) Then
        Do While Transform < 10
            Transform *= 10
        Loop
    End If
End If
```

Or here's a version that is more generic so you can use it to get any number of decimal places:

```
Function Transform(ByVal toTransform As Decimal, ByVal numberOfPlaces As Integer) As Decimal
    Transform = toTransform
    Dim min = 10 ^ (numberOfPlaces - 1)
    Dim max = 10 ^ numberOfPlaces

    If (Transform >= max) Then
        Do While Transform >= max
            Transform /= 10
        Loop
    ElseIf (Transform < min) Then
        Do While Transform < min
            Transform *= 10
        Loop
    End If
End Function
```

Basically, it multiplies or divides the number by 10 which moves the decimal point in the required direction.  It does so until the result is less than or equal to the maximum value in that range and greater than or equal to the minimum value in that range.

Comment: okay, what would be the best approach to make it work with 123.12 but also with big numbers like 123456.12 etc..

Comment: roryap, beautiful code, thanks for those wonderful samples. the second one did it for me..